# Octave fplot abs looks very strange

Tags: gnuplot, octave

```
f = @(x)(abs(x))
fplot(f, [-1, 1]
```

Freshly installed octave, with no configuration edited. It results in the following image, where it looks as if it is constant for a while around 0, looking more like a \_/  than a \/:

[image: plotted function]

Why does it look so different from a usual plot of the absolute value near 0? How can this be fixed?

Comment: The default installation of Octave doesn't use gnuplot anymore, but typically Qt (what is the output of `graphics_toolkit`?). It seems to me that your question is unrelated to gnuplot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `fplot` is written in Octave it is relatively easy to read. Its location can be found using the `which` command. On my system this gives:

```
octave:1> which fplot
'fplot' is a function from the file /usr/share/octave/5.2.0/m/plot/draw/fplot.m
```

Examining `fplot.m` reveals that the function to be plotted, f(x), is evaluated at n equally spaced points between the given limits. The algorithm for determining n starts at line 192 and can be summarised as follows:

1. n is initially chosen to be 8 (unless specified differently by the user)
2. Construct a vector of arguments using a coarser grid of n/2 + 1 points:
   `x0 = linspace (limits(1), limits(2), n/2 + 1)'`
   (The linspace function will accept a non-integer value for the number of points, which it rounds down)
3. Calculate the corresponding values:
   `y0 = f(x0)`
4. Construct a vector of arguments using a grid of n points:
   `x = linspace (limits(1), limits(2), n)'`
5. Calculate the corresponding values:
   `y = f(x0)`
6. Construct a vector of values corresponding to the members of x but calculated from x0 and y0 by linear interpolation using the function `interp1()`:
   `yi = interp1 (x0, y0, x, "linear")`
7. Calculate an error metric using the following formula:
   `err = 0.5 * max (abs ((yi - y) ./ (yi + y + eps))(:))`
   That is, `err` is proportional to the maximum difference between the calculated and linearly interpolated values.
8. If `err` is greater than `tol` (2e-3 unless specified by the user) then put n = 2*(n-1) and repeat. Otherwise plot(x,y).

Because `abs(x)` is essentially a pair of straight lines, if x0 contains zero then the linearly interpolated values will always exactly match their corresponding calculated values and `err` will be exactly zero, so the above algorithm will terminate at the end of the first iteration.  If x doesn't contain zero then `plot(x,y)` will be called on a set of points that doesn't include the 'cusp' of the function and the strange behaviour will occur.

This will happen if the limits are equally spaced either side of zero and floor(n/2 + 1) is odd, which is the case for the default values (limits = [-5, 5], n = 8).

The behaviour can be avoided by choosing a combination of `n` and `limits` so that either of the following is the case:
a) the set of m = floor(n/2 + 1) equally spaced points doesn't include zero or
b) the set of n equally spaced points does include zero.

For example, limits equally spaced either side of zero and odd n will plot correctly . This will not work for n=5, though, because, strangely, if the user inputs n=5, `fplot.m`  substitutes 8 for it (I'm not sure why it does this, I think it may be a mistake). So `fplot(@abs, [-1, 1], 3)` and `fplot(@abs, [-1, 1], 7)` will plot correctly but `fplot(@abs, [-1, 1], 5)` won't.

(n/2 + 1) is odd, and therefore x0 contains zero for symmetrical limits, only for every 2nd even n. This is why it plots correctly with n=6 because for that value n/2 + 1 = 4, so x0 doesn't contain zero. This is also the case for n=10, 14, 18 and so on.

Choosing slightly asymmetrical limits will also do the trick, try: `fplot(@abs, [-1.1, 1.2])`

Comment: Why does `fplot(@abs, [-1, 1], N=6)` produce a correct plot (see my answer)? The limits are equally spaced and N is even...

Comment: Just edited my answer to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says: "*fplot* works best with continuous functions. Functions with discontinuities are unlikely to plot well. This restriction may be removed in the future." so it is probably a bug/feature of the function itself that can't be fixed except by the developers. The ordinary `plot()` function works fine:

```
x = [-1 0 1];
y = abs(x);
plot(x, y);
```

Comment: Abs is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

The weird shape comes from the sampling rate, i.e. at how many points the function is evaluated. This is controlled by the parameter `N` of `fplot` The default call seems to accidentally skip x=0, and with `fplot(@abs, [-1, 1], N=5)` I get the same funny shape like you:
[image]

However, trying out different values of `N` can yield the correct shape, try e.g. `fplot(@abs, [-1, 1], N=6)`:

[image]

Although in general I would suggest to use way higher numbers, like `N=100`.

Comment: That makes sense. Same effect is visible at `N=100` to me tho (altho smaller).

Comment: @Carla_display Indeed, `N=100` hits a problematic spot again, `N=101` looks fine to me. If you think your question is resolved, please consider to accept this answer.

Comment: @Elraid yes, i believe the issue here happens when N is even. If N is odd, then it hits the origin. So even `N=3` works perfectly fine for this function